# What's a good way to give a character a realistic edge in a post-apocalypse setting?

Tags: post-apocalypse, worldbuilding-process, combat

What's a realistic way to give a protagonist character a fighting edge against enemies with great numerical superiority, without making them superheroes? What's something believable?

Comment: Without knowing anything about your post-apocalyptic world it's not really possible to answer. What are the threats? What kind of devasted environment are they living in? What is the technology level?

Comment: What type of enemies? Zombies? Terminators? Other people? A gigantic swarm of rabid ferrets?

Comment: Is it possible to _evade_ these enemies, or is confrontation essential to the world you're constructing?

Answer (score 1):

This verges into Brainstorming territory - but the biggest thing IMO would be this:

**The ability to live off of the land**

Expert level Hunting, Fishing, Gathering and survival skills.

Now, first up - this doesn't make them a super hero, it's entirely plausible for an individual, even a city-dweller who is an avid outdoorsman to acquire those skills.

Why?

Well, being limited to one place makes you an easy target. It's a matter of When, not If. Especially against a numerically superior foe. They know where you are, or at the very least, know your approximate location - and from then on, it's just a numbers and time game.

To use an example - You have to be lucky *all* the time, they just have to get lucky once.

Not being limited to a single area and being constantly on the move immediately gives your protagonist a big advantage.

Next up is that by being able to live off the land, your hero is able to avoid populated areas or obvious areas. Back Country in most places is generally pretty large and even with modern technology (IR, GPS etc.) it's very easy to miss someone you are actively looking for, let alone someone who is actively trying to hide.

An experienced outdoorsman might be able to live off the land near-indefinitely, constantly shifting location - 20 or so miles in a day isn't unrealistic - and that is a **Massive** area to try and search - it's the equivalent of nearly 4,000 square kilometers.

In addition - knowing how to hunt and stalk prey gives you an advantage should you come against an isolated enemy combatant and you want to *relieve* them of their equipment.

There are other skills that could be learnt (especially if your character has a Military background) that would be useful, such as Evasion training - but at the core - knowing how to survive in the bush and being fit/healthy will give your protagonist the best chance to survive.

Comment: Note that, in the long term, this means the most lethal portable weapon you'll have access to is a bow and arrow, and the most lethal weapon you'll have overall is probably punji stakes or a deadfall trap.

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE - Sure - but those options are plenty lethal, when employed by someone who knows what they are doing. The VietCong showed just how nasty Punji sticks can be against the might of the US Military.

Answer (score 0):

A large stockpile of well-preserved ammunition from the pre-apocalypse civilization. That would give them to more and better firepower than people relying on scavenged ammunition or crudely-made blackpowder weaponry.

[Credit to this blogpost from ACOUP](https://acoup.blog/2022/08/05/fireside-friday-august-5-2022/) for the idea. In particular, this quote is thought-provoking for any  post-apocalyptic worldbuilder:

> Unlike in many of these settings where guns are scarce, it would be cartridges that would be scarce (credit, I suppose, to Metro, where they are in fact so notionally scarce they’ve become the de facto currency); the world’s supply of guns are more than capable of shooting the world’s supply of bullets long before they all wear out their barrels and actions.